# How to make a div right after a text box?

Tags: css, html

How to make a div right after a text box(in the same line) ?

```
        <!--Text box -->
        Title: <input type="text" name="textbox1" placeholder="Type here"
            class="inputs" />
        <!-- dropdown menu -->
        <div class="select-style">
            <select class="dropdown" Name="color" onchange="">
                <option value="" class="label" value="">Text Color</option>
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps use `<span>` instead?

Comment: You can either float the elements or use `div.select-style{display:inline-block;}`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this rule to your css file:

```
.select-style{
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX8fs/)

Or if you wish to use inline styles add this to your div:

```
 <div style="display: inline" class="select-style">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Title: <input type="text" name="textbox1" placeholder="Type here"
        class="inputs" />

    <!-- dropdown menu -->
    <span class="select-style">
        <select class="dropdown" Name="color" onchange="">
            <option value="" class="label" value="">Text Color</option>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
        </select>
    </span>
```

its working for me

Answer (score 0):

use CSS:

```
.select-style {display:inline-block;}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use **span**, because it's an **inline element**. And **div** is a **block element** which always breaks line.

See JFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VC7DD/

```
<!--Text box -->
Title: <input type="text" name="textbox1" placeholder="Type here"
    class="inputs" />
<!-- dropdown menu -->
<span class="select-style">
    <select class="dropdown" Name="color" onchange="">
        <option value="" class="label" value="">Text Color</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select>
</span>
```